Error hitting API with redis - SerializationException
I am currently learning Redis and using API endpoints to store and retrieve data using redis datatypes. When I hit an API endpoint (/lrange/person) I get the following error message
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize] with root cause


API, I am trying to hit (localhost:8080/lrange/person).This API can be seen in PersonController.java and is under List (datatype). I am trying to get all or a range of values depending on start and end parameters in the list and Typecasting to a Person (entity here - can be seen in Person.java). The API gives a 500 Internal Server Error.
Here is the full stack trace
2024-05-10T15:12:33.167-07:00  INFO 23153 --- [demo-spring] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-05-10T15:12:33.352-07:00 ERROR 23153 --- [demo-spring] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demospring.Person
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:802) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:80) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2059) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1925) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2248) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:538) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:496) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:899) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1101) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2442) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2280) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:538) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:496) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:71) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:75) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:37) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:106) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationUtils.deserializeValues(SerializationUtils.java:54) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:68) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeValues(AbstractOperations.java:286) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations.lambda$range$9(DefaultListOperations.java:159) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:396) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:97) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations.range(DefaultListOperations.java:159) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at com.example.demoredis.PersonController.lrange(PersonController.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]


Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2:SIGINT)


DemoRedisApplication.java
package com.example.demoredis;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoRedisApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoRedisApplication.class, args);
    }

}


Person.java
package com.example.demoredis;

import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double creditScore;
}


PersonController.java
package com.example.demoredis;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private static final String PERSON_KEY_PREFIX = "per::";
    private static final String PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX = "per_list";

    // ---------------- String ----------------------------------

    @GetMapping("/string/person")
    public Person getPerson(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
        String key = getKey(id);
        return (Person) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
    }

    @PostMapping("/string/person")
    public void insertPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        String key = getKey(person.getId());
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, person);
    }

    public String getKey(long id) {
        return PERSON_KEY_PREFIX + id;
    }

    // --------------------- List ---------------------

    @GetMapping("/lrange/person")
    public List<Person> lrange(@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int start,
                               @RequestParam(value = "end", required = false, defaultValue = "-1") int end){
        return redisTemplate.opsForList()
                .range(PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX, start, end)
                .stream()
                .map(x -> (Person) x)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @PostMapping("/lpush/person")
    public void insertListPersonLeft(@RequestBody List<Person> personList) {
        redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPushAll(PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX, personList);
    }

    @PostMapping("/rpush/person")
    public void insertListPersonRight(@RequestBody List<Person> personList) {
        redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPushAll(PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX, personList);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/lpop/person")
    public Person deletePersonLeft(@RequestParam(value = "count", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int count) {
        return (Person) redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop(PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/lpoplist/person")
    public List<Person> deletePersonLeftList(@RequestParam(value = "count", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int count) {
        return redisTemplate.opsForList()
                .leftPop(PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX, count)
                .stream()
                .map(x -> (Person) x)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("rpop/person")
    public Person deletePersonRight(@RequestParam(value = "count", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int count) {
        return (Person) redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPop(PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX);
    }

    public String getListKey(long id) {
        return PERSON_LIST_KEY_PREFIX + id;
    }
}


PersonConfig.java
package com.example.demoredis;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

@Configuration
public class PersonConfig {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> getTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}


pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-redis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Thank you for taking out time to help me out.

Posted exception is about com.example.demospring.Person. Posted code is com.example.demoredis.Person. demospring != demoredis.

Pretty sure copied the code from my IDE into stack overflow and I wrote the code myself, so not sure from where demospring is coming up, just moved the code elsewhere and wrote new from scratch to encounter the same error. Thanks for the comment though.
